# Overflow property on outer container resulting in non-functioning of negative margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, margin

I am rendering a list and I want the hover color over it to **span the width of the outer container**. I am using a `negative margin` to accomplish that. It works fine without giving `overflow` property to the **outer wrapper**, but when I am giving `overflow` property, it gets **restricted to the width of the list item** and doesn't span till the width of the outer container.

The code below shows the expected behavior without overflow property,

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
}
li {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 -30px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <ul class='wrapper' style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
        <li>List item 4</li>
        <li>List item 5</li>
        <li>List item 6</li>
        <li>List item 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code when adding, overflow-y: auto to the outer wrapper,

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
li {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 -30px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <ul class='wrapper' style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
        <li>List item 4</li>
        <li>List item 5</li>
        <li>List item 6</li>
        <li>List item 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve the **expected behavior** while using `overflow-y: auto` property on the outer wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using negative margins and just pass the paddings to li from ul.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
li {
  padding: 15px 40px;
}
li:first-child {margin-top: 35px;}
li:last-child {margin-bottom: 35px;}

li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <ul class='wrapper' style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
        <li>List item 4</li>
        <li>List item 5</li>
        <li>List item 6</li>
        <li>List item 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative values should be avoided if possible. In your case it is.
I've changed your html a little bit in order to make it behave like you described. Check out the code below.

If you want to add more content keeping the offsets above or below the list, you can do it by reusing the wrapper.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#list {
  padding: 0;
  height: 800px;
}
li {
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div style="padding: 20px 0;">--content--</div>
  </div>
  <ul class='wrapper' id="list" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
    <li>List item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div style="padding: 20px 0;">--content--</div>
  </div>
</div>
```